# JavaScript object as function parameter

Tags: scala.js

I'm writting a function transpiled with Scala.js that should accept any random JavaScript object.

Ex:

```
// This has been transpiled using Scala.js
var my_service = new com.myself.Service();

// This is plain JavaScript 
var result1 = service({ hello: "yolo" });
var result2 = service({ whatever: "ok", really: { yes: "right", no: "don't" } });
```

However, I can't find the input type that matches it.

- What would be the Scala-function signature to get such a thing?
- Could it be used then as a "Scala/JS case class" easily?

*Note (if it helps giving a direction for the answers): these objects have, in the real life, an expected schema but it cannot be created as JS object generated from Scala.js since it comes from another consumed service.*

Comment: Those are JavaScript object literals (containing strings and more object literals). They aren't JSON. If you extracted them from the JavaScript and put them in a file of their own then they still wouldn't be JSON as JSON only allows strings as property names (and not identifiers as you are using here).

Comment: Alright. I'll rephrase it. Thanks.

Comment: "Object" would be sufficient

Answer (score 1):

Since the objects have an expected schema, its probably easiest to define a facade type:

```
@js.native
trait Args extends js.Object {
  val hello: js.UndefOr[String]
  val whatever: js.UndefOr[String]
  val really: js.UndefOr[ReallyArgs]
}

@js.native
trait Really extends js.Object {
  val yes: String
  val no: String
}

def myMethod(args: Args): Unit = {
  println(args.hello)
  println(args.really.map(_.yes))
}
```